# How can the OGRE3D SceneManager really find *any* SceneNode?

Tags: c++, ogre

### TL;DR;

How can the `SceneManager` actually find any `SceneNode` *regardless of where it happens to be in the graph* when:

1. The `SceneManager::createSceneNode(...)` method explicitly claims that the nodes created are *not* part of the graph?¹, *and*
2. `SceneNode`s can independently create their own children without the `SceneManager`'s knowledge?²

¹ <sub>The SM does not automatically turn the scene nodes it creats into children of other nodes (e.g. root); you have to manually call `addChild` on a node for that</sub>

² <sub>The client can simply write `sceneManager->getRootSceneNode()->createChildSceneNode("Child");`, and the SM wouldn't know about the new child's existence</sub>

---

### Background

I was going over the source code in OGRE3D and came across the following piece of documentation on the `SceneManager` class (>> << emphasis added):

```
/** Retrieves a named SceneNode from the scene graph.
    @remarks
        If you chose to name a SceneNode as you created it, or if you
        happened to make a note of the generated name, you can look it
        up >>wherever it is in the scene graph<< using this method.
        @note Throws an exception if the named instance does not exist
*/
virtual SceneNode* getSceneNode(const String& name) const;
```

When you look at the implementation, you see:

```
SceneNode* SceneManager::getSceneNode(const String& name) const
{
    SceneNodeList::const_iterator i = mSceneNodes.find(name);

    if (i == mSceneNodes.end())
    {
        OGRE_EXCEPT(Exception::ERR_ITEM_NOT_FOUND, "SceneNode '" + name + "' not found.",
            "SceneManager::getSceneNode");
    }

    return i->second;
}
```

So far, so good. We can see that the SM searches for your requested `SceneNode` in its own `SceneNodeList` named `mSceneNodes`. The part I'm trying to figure out is that the documentation claims it can find a node "wherever it is in the scene graph". New `SceneNode`s are only added into the `mSceneNodes` list when using `SceneManager::createSceneNode(...)`. The documentation for the SM's `createSceneNode` method says (>> << emphasis added):

```
/** Creates an instance of a SceneNode with a given name.
    @remarks
        Note that this >>does not add the SceneNode to the scene hierarchy<<.
        This method is for convenience, since it allows an instance to
        be created for which the SceneManager is responsible for
        allocating and releasing memory, which is convenient in complex
        scenes.
    @par
        To include the returned SceneNode in the scene, use the addChild
        method of the SceneNode which is to be it's parent.
    @par
        Note that this method takes a name parameter, which makes the node easier to
    retrieve directly again later.
*/
virtual SceneNode* createSceneNode(const String& name);
```

At the same time, if you look at the `SceneNode` class, it has its own `createChild(const String& name, ...)` method, which clearly does *not* add its own children into the `SceneManager`'s list, as shown below:

```
SceneNode* SceneNode::createChildSceneNode(const Vector3& inTranslate,
    const Quaternion& inRotate)
{
    return static_cast<SceneNode*>(this->createChild(inTranslate, inRotate));
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
SceneNode* SceneNode::createChildSceneNode(const String& name, const Vector3& inTranslate,
    const Quaternion& inRotate)
{
    return static_cast<SceneNode*>(this->createChild(name, inTranslate, inRotate));
}
```

This means that if the client program says `node.createChildSceneNode(...);`, the `SceneManager` would *not* be aware of the existence of the new child node, AFAIK, so it'd never be able to find it.

I've been studying the source code for a while now and I've not found an answer to this question. I looked at the `BspSceneManager` and the `BspSceneNode` just to see if I could spot something else, but came up empty.

---

For the sake of completeness/reference, the most recent commit currently available in the master branch is:

```
commit 3b13abbdcce146b2813a6cc3bedf16d1d6084340
Author: mkultra333 <unknown>
Date:   Sun May 8 19:31:39 2016 +0800
```

Comment: i just thought it's strange you talk about `createChild` but show code for `createChildSceneNode` and added a couple of examples, stay well though, bye

Comment: @strangeqargo: I've fixed the typo, which I'm assuming was the `node.createChild` part. In either case, it wouldn't make a practical different in the question, which is more specifically about the Scene Manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's no wonder this part confuses you because it's part of over-OOP from more than a decade ago. Some like it, some hate it.

The answer however, is quite simple if once you know what to look for:
The code for `Node::createChild` is the following:

```
Node* newNode = createChildImpl( sceneType );
//...
return newNode;
```

It actually delegates creation to `createChildImpl` (the "implementer"). This function is a pure virtual function, thus `SceneNode` *must* overload.

When we go to `SceneNode::createChildImpl`, we get:

```
Node* SceneNode::createChildImpl(const String& name)
{
    return mCreator->_createSceneNode( name );
}
```

`mCreator` is a `SceneManager` pointer variable. So there you go: The `SceneManager` does get informed when a `SceneNode` is created via `createChildSceneNode`.

Note however an implementation (e.g. `BspSceneNode` in `BspSceneManager`) may overload `createChildImpl` and not inform the `SceneManager`; or they may.

Placing a breakpoint inside `SceneManager::_createSceneNode` and checking out the callstack will save you a lot of headaches though.

Comment: Argh. I had indeed looked at some of the `createChildImpl` ones, but I was looking for them in the leaf classes (e.g. `BspSceneNode`), which did not actually inform the `SceneManager` of it, and when I looked at the `SceneManager::createSceneNodeImpl` I only found `return OGRE_NEW SceneNode(this, name);`. So, I guess I had some bad luck re the leaf node implementation I ended up looking at, but this makes sense and found it at the locations you specified. Thanks a lot. (BTW, I'm not really running/using the engine; I'm just reading/studying it, so no stack trace available there ._. )